# Run pytest within docker container while running github action

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pytest, github-actions, postgis

In my Django project, I have psql/postgis database engine. To run tests, I need the testdb to be of same configuration. So, I did a docker setup of the repo, which gets the project up and running. I have django server and postgis database in docker-compose.yml.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.0'

services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:16-3.4
    container_name: docker_db
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=test
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    expose:
      - 5432

  test-web:
    build: .
    container_name: docker_web
    command:
          sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
        - POSTGRES_HOST=db
        - POSTGRES_DATABASE=test
        - POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    depends_on:
      - db
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y postgis aptitude && apt-get update && aptitude install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev python3-gdal binutils libproj-dev

RUN pip install poetry

COPY . /code/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-root
```

```
# .github\workflows\tests.yml

name: Pytest

on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: docker-compose up
        env:
          COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI: 1
        run: docker-compose up -d
      - name: Check running containers
        run: docker ps -a
      - name: Check logs
        run: docker-compose logs
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: docker exec docker_web bash -c "pytest"
```

I fire these commands locally in the same order, and it works fine. Pytest finds the test files and tests them successfully.
(Ofcourse, running pytest works without docker too. But I need this for github action.)

```
`docker-compose up -d`
`docker exec docker_web bash -c "pytest"`
```

Now, issue that I have with this setup is in github actions. Github actions gives `Error: Process completed with exit code 137.`, meaning process was killed due to running out of memory. I tried running pytest with single file as well, but error remained same.

Can someone tell, if this approach is correct or not. Or any alternatives to fix the memory issue.
Or any alternatives to run pytest within container in github actions.